# Forcing an app to clean itself?

Tags: ios

I've been swiping around the home screen on my iPhone when I see the text under the Facebook logo switch to `cleaning...`, but it's nothing that I made it do, is there any way to tell an app to clean itself?

Comment: "Cleaning..."? I've never heard of apps being cleaned. Is your iPhone Jailbroken?

Comment: Nope.  It's not jail broken.  Maybe only Facebook does it.

Comment: Do you have anything installed under Settings > General > Profiles & Device Management?

Comment: Just an certificate.

Comment: And you intentionally installed it and know what it's for, right?

Comment: That's correct. I knowingly installed it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the home screen?

Comment: No I can't, it happens very quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this OS X Daily article](http://osxdaily.com/2014/04/07/ios-app-name-cleaning/) that should answer your question.

Basically, when storage is low, iOS detects apps that take up a lot of space with old caches and temporary files and automatically delete them. It's perfectly normal. The user can't force iOS to clean apps, though.

Comment: But there isn't a way to force it?  Thanks Apple!

Comment: @leeand00 You should suggest it to Apple.

Comment: How do you do that?  And something tells me it would be against their business model.

Comment: @leeand00 It kind of is, but it wouldn't hurt to suggest it at http://www.apple.com/feedback/ if it's a feature you really want.